# JOIN the Same Table.Field Twice but for Different Records

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have this table and it has requests from a user `id(int)` to a `supervisor(int)` and I need to get the name of the user and the name of the supervisor on each record.  Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT
pdv_request.req_id,
pdv_request.data_caixa,
pdv_request.turno,
pdv_request.terminal,
pdv_request.nro_venda,
pdv_request.valor_venda,
pdv_request.razao,
usuarios.nome as username

FROM pdv_request

LEFT JOIN usuarios ON pdv_request.operador = usuarios.nome
LEFT JOIN usuarios ON pdv_request.supervisor = usuarios.nome 
 
WHERE
pdv_request.data_caixa NOT BETWEEN :dini AND :dfin

ORDER BY
pdv_request.data_caixa ASC
```

`usuarios` is the table with the details of the users(operators, supervisors,etc...), also the :dini and :dfinal is just parameters that the DAC to replace with the date, and I need to get the content of the field `nome` for the operators and for the supervisors. I'm pretty sure this is possible, but I don't know how to reference the second name on the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select two tables of the same type, and select fields from both of these tables, you need to use aliases to distinguish them, like so:

```
SELECT user1.nome as username1
SELECT user2.nome as username2

[...]

LEFT JOIN usuarios AS users1 ON pdv_request.operador = usuarios.nome
LEFT JOIN usuarios AS users2 ON pdv_request.supervisor = usuarios.nome
```

Take a look at the MySQL dev manual...

> A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name....
>
> ...
>
> `tbl_name [[AS] alias] [index_hint]` (Source: [Dev.MySQL.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).)